# best way to retrieve identity column value in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, identity-column

I have a stored procedure for CRUD operation with table insert. I have just created stored procedure like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[parent_SUD]
(
    @PK_ParentID int= null,
    @ParentName varchar(50)= null,
    @Gender varchar(10)= null,
    @Ocuption varchar(25)= null,
    @Address varchar(200)= null,
    @MobileNo varchar(15)= null,
    @PhoneNo varchar(15)= null,
    @EmailID varchar(200)= null,
    @Entry_By int= null,
    @ParentPhoto varbinary(max)=null,
    @SP_Type varchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN TRY 
 if (@SP_Type='Add')  
  begin 

insert into [dbo].[parents]
           ([ParentName]
           ,[Gender]
           ,[Ocuption]
           ,[Address]
           ,[MobileNo]
           ,[PhoneNo]
           ,[EmailID]
           ,[ParentPhoto]
           ,[Entry_By])
     values
           (@ParentName
           ,@Gender
           ,@Ocuption
           ,@Address
           ,@MobileNo
           ,@PhoneNo
           ,@EmailID
           ,@ParentPhoto
           ,@Entry_By)
     return SCOPE_IDENTITY()   
 End 
 else if (@SP_Type='Edit') 
       .... return 1
 else if (@SP_Type='Delete') 
 begin 
  ...return 1
End  
End Try 
 BEGIN CATCH 
 ......
 );
 END CATCH;
```

here i can not receive scope identity with return value.. at sp type 'Add' i can't receive identity column value. it's always return 1.....

what's going wrong here..

Comment: I would guess that there is something else occurring here that is not shown in your code extract.  If it was executing `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()` then the procedure would return at that point with the new identity value.  Do you have any triggers on your `parents` table?

Comment: nothing...no triggers

Comment: First, You would be better off writing a different procedure for each action - You'll get a much shorter, readable and maintainable code this way.

Second, you shouldn't use `return` to get the value generated for the identity back to the caller. Instead, use an `output` parameter.

Comment: There is no ultimate best way. There are four ways you can get the value generated for the identity column back, each with it's own use case. For more information, read my blog post entitled [Use the right tool to get identity values back after an insert](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/03/use-the-right-tool-to-get-identity-values-back-after-an-insert/)

Answer (score 1):

Use an `output` clause:

```
declare table @ids (id int);

insert into . . .
    output inserted.id into @ids
    values ( . . . );
```

Then you can do whatever you want with `@ids`.  Note that it is a table and it should have only one row.  So this should be fine:

```
declare @id int;

select @id = id
from @ids;
```

Comment: @shalingajjar . . . I think the answer is pretty clear on the changes that need to be made.  Are you unclear about something?

Comment: When inserting a single row, what's the benefit of using the `output` clause over `scope_identity()`?

Comment: i just want this returnvalue to another record entry as @parentID